# My script runs perfectly through bash, but using a service to call it gives me errors

Tags: java, raspberry-pi4, systemctl

I am currently trying to develop a program that displays repeating images (using Java and Jframe) using a raspberry pi 4.

However, I have a small shell script that compiles (and runs) said program which works perfectly when I call it manually. However, I am trying to have this happen on boot through creating a custom service that calls upon that script. The problem arises when the compiled program is being run as I get the error

> No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.

Now I did a bit of research and have tried to use the command (in the shell script) `export DISPLAY=:0.0` however, this also gives an error of

> Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.

I am not quite sure on why the service is trying to connect to a X11 window server either.

This is the service:

```
[Unit]
Description=myservice custom script

[Service]
RequiresMountsFor=/media/pi/PICS
ExecStart=+/bin/bash /home/pi/Desktop/PicScript.sh
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And finally, the little shell script:

```
javac /media/pi/PICS/App/App.java
export DISPLAY=:0.0
java -classpath /media/pi/PICS/App App
```

Comment: Maybe your X server hasn't started yet?

Comment: when you log into a linux GUI, this environment variable will be set.

Comment: @tgdavies Does my X server need to be running to display locally as well? Like I said, running this script straight from bash works just fine :(            beginnings are hard haha

Comment: @ScaryWombat Is there any way to force a service to use the same display? Setting PATH's maybe? Thanks

Comment: It has been many years since I have done something like this, but maybe a vncserver is necessary e.g. x11vnc?

Comment: Your DISPLAY variable is pointing at a local X server. I'm assuming that you have a monitor plugged in to the pi's video port. That image is created by an X server running locally on the pi, which X clients like your Java program connect to so they can render their UIs.